# How to dynamically add source to the audio

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to add audio file dynamically using jquery. I have written code like this:

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" style="width:400px;height:30px;" controls="controls">
<source id="oggSource"  type="audio/ogg" />
<source id="mp3Source" src="~/Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

The source for mp3 is my application root folder. It is working. I want to add file in local folder like

```
<audio id="audioPlayer" style="width:400px;height:30px;" controls="controls">
<source id="oggSource"  type="audio/ogg" />
<source id="mp3Source" src="D:\Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

It is not playing. I want to play the file in the local computer.

And i want to add the file dynamically. I have a browse button. In that i will select the 
audio file and i want to add the file dynamically using jquery and play that. How can i suppose to do that. I have added source like:

```
  $('#mp3Source').attr('src', 'D:\Kalimba.mp3').detach().appendTo($("#audioPlayer"));
```

What mistake i have did.

Comment: `'D:\Kalimba.mp3'` what you are trying to access is non professional, just place all your mp3 files in the your root project directory like `project/audios/mp3_files` which is easy to access all resources related to your project.

Comment: but my requirement is user will select the file from his local drive and the selected file has to be play.

Comment: I dont think its a mistake , after all its a security issue, if your app can access users local drive for fetching files, what makes it reliable from stealing files / inserting viruses..anyways make sure its possible first..!!

Comment: @codebrain but that code is not working for me. Is there any alternate

Comment: I don't know karthik , Go to Javascript/Jquery chat room and chat with experts..